# (caspol -security off) does not work

Tags: c#, batch-file, caspol

I am running a batch file which compiles hundreds of DLL's and programs written in C#.

Unfortunately, I get error:

```
Web deployment task failed. (Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.)
```

Googling sent me to CAS problems. It then sent me to:

```
caspol -security off
```

I found this line of code on MSDN site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/66ad9kf0(v=vs.100).aspx

I run this command from VS 2010 command prompt both 32 and 64 bit.

Unfortunately, console returns error:

ERROR: Invalid option: -security

1. How can I solve the problem with my batch file?
2. Do I really need to sort CAS issue on my machine- if so then how can I do it?

Thank you!